# How to get all packages' code coverage together in Go?

Tags: unit-testing, go, code-coverage

I have a library consisting of several packages. When running tests, I am using '-cover' flag and its showing the coverage information for each package individually.Like follows:

```
--- PASS: TestSampleTestSuite (0.00s)
PASS
coverage: 28.7% of statements
ok      github.com/path/to/package1 13.021s
?       github.com/path/to/package2 [no test files]

=== RUN   TestAbc
--- PASS: TestAbc (0.43s)
PASS
coverage: 27.7% of statements
```

Is there any way to get a full coverage overview easily to get good idea about coverage on the whole project?

Update: Here is the go test command I am using

```
go test ./... -v -short -p 1 -cover
```

Answer (score 58):

EDIT: Things have changed since I wrote this answer. See the release notes of Go 1.10: https://golang.org/doc/go1.10#test :

> The go test -coverpkg flag now interprets its argument as a
>   comma-separated list of patterns to match against the dependencies of
>   each test, not as a list of packages to load anew. For example, go
>   test -coverpkg=all is now a meaningful way to run a test with coverage
>   enabled for the test package and all its dependencies. Also, the go
>   test -coverprofile option is now supported when running multiple
>   tests.

You can now run

```
go test -v -coverpkg=./... -coverprofile=profile.cov ./...
go tool cover -func profile.cov
```

---

**Old answer**

Here is a bash script extracted from https://github.com/h12w/gosweep :

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -e

echo 'mode: count' > profile.cov

for dir in $(find . -maxdepth 10 -not -path './.git*' -not -path '*/_*' -type d);
do
if ls $dir/*.go &> /dev/null; then
    go test -short -covermode=count -coverprofile=$dir/profile.tmp $dir
    if [ -f $dir/profile.tmp ]
    then
        cat $dir/profile.tmp | tail -n +2 >> profile.cov
        rm $dir/profile.tmp
    fi
fi
done

go tool cover -func profile.cov
```

Comment: Well, it still shows the coverage info per package basis, which I am getting from my given command. Any tweaks to get a overall coverage info?

Comment: The very last line it outputs is this : `total: (statements)  99.3%`, is that not what you want @Rana ?

Comment: I got the "bad mode line" too. I had to add the line `echo "mode: count" > profile.cov` in the beginning.

Comment: Thanks, added to the answer

Comment: Am I right in thinking this only produces a coverage for those files that have some tests? Also I had to add `-not -path './vendor/*'` to ignore vendored packages.

Comment: @danielcooperxyz is correct.  Packages which don't have tests will produce a 1-line profile containing `mode: count`.  The tail command will remove this line and append nothing to profile.cov.  This then prevents `go tool cover -func profile.cov` from accurately calculating the total coverage.  For what it's worth, `go test -coverprofile=profile.cov ./...` is functionally equivalent to most of this script and suffers from the same inaccuracy.

Comment: How are the added flags in go 1.10 relevant for this?

Comment: @rubystallion added an example on how to use them

Comment: In my particular case, continue not very pretty, but it works `line_total=$(go tool cover -func profile.cov | grep -e 'total:')` next `total_int=$(echo "$line_total" | grep -o '[0-9.]*' | awk '{print int($1+0.5)}')` finally the comparison in case of requiring to inform `if (( $total_int < $threshold )) ; then`