# Go Coverage over multiple package and Gitlab Coverage Badge

Tags: go, testing, code-coverage

I'm trying to display an accurate coverage badge for my gitlab project.

Thing is I have several packages, in gitlab-ci.yml, I run

```
go test $(go list ./... | grep -v /vendor/) -v -coverprofile .testCoverage.txt
```

and my output is something like that:

```
$ go test -coverprofile=coverage.txt -covermode=atomic ./...
 ok     gitlab.com/[MASKED]/pam 10.333s coverage: 17.2% of statements
 ok     gitlab.com/[MASKED]/pam/acquisition 0.004s  coverage: 57.7% of statements
 ok     gitlab.com/[MASKED]/pam/acquisition/api 0.005s  coverage: 72.1% of statements
 ok     gitlab.com/[MASKED]/pam/acquisition/ftp 24.936s coverage: 73.1% of statements
 ok     gitlab.com/[MASKED]/pam/repartition 0.004s  coverage: 90.1% of statements
```

And my Test coverage parsing regex in Gitlab is:

```
^coverage:\s(\d+(?:\.\d+)?%)
```

If I check the .testCoverage, I get a lot of lines like that:

```
 gitlab.com/[MASKED]/pam/repartition/repartition.go:54.33,56.5 1 1
```

So, it gives me a result of `90.1%` when it is only the coverage of the last package.

How should I do it ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33444968/how-to-get-all-packages-code-coverage-together-in-go),

I just needed another command:

```
go tool cover -func profile.cov
```

That will give you the result:

```
✗ go tool cover -func profile.cov

gitlab.com/[MASKED]/pam/acquisition/acquisition.go:17:                       FetchAll                        0.0%
gitlab.com/[MASKED]/pam/acquisition/acquisition.go:32:                       TransformData                   100.0%
gitlab.com/[MASKED]/pam/acquisition/acquisition_mocks.go:13:                 FetchMeters                     0.0%
gitlab.com/[MASKED]/pam/repartition/repartition.go:102:                      GroupMetersByOperation          100.0%
gitlab.com/[MASKED]/pam/repartition/repartition.go:111:                      SetProrataRedistributed         71.4%
total:                                                                          (statements)                    68.7%
```

In gitlab, you can change the regex:

```
^coverage:\s(\d+(?:\.\d+)?%)
```

By

```
\(statements\)(?:\s+)?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?%)
```

Now, if you have mocks, coverage will include them, so you must remove them following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50065448/how-to-ignore-generated-files-from-go-test-coverage):

```
go test . -coverprofile profile.cov.tmp
cat profile.cov.tmp | grep -v "_mocks.go" > cover.out
tool cover -func profile.cov
```

Off course, all your mocks should be in files with suffix : `_mocks.go`

And it should work.

Hope it helps others!